# How can I Redirect any URL whether it starts with http or https into particular url (abc.com) when user is connected to my wifi in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apache2

If a user types (http://www.espncricinfo.com/) I want to redirect the user to (http://abc.com). If the user type (https://askubuntu.com) I want to redirect the user to (http://abc.com).

Comment: I'm not possible to do with `HTTPS`, you will always have certificate problems on a user's browser. And instead of getting redirected, they will see an error page in their browser that the certificate is invalid for that domain.

Answer (score 0):

Such a redirection would need to be done at your router/access point, and if you're just using a standard SOHO router, it's probably not viable to do so. What you need to do is set up port forwarding from the internal interface on your router (your LAN) to a specific host (your server) on ports 80 (http) and 443 (https).

If you're only concerned with doing this on your wireless and you have a separate access point, you should be able to plug your access point into your server and send traffic from the wifi network through your server. If you don't want the wireless hosts to have internet access, then this is all you really need to do. If you do want them to have internet access, you'll also need to set up [iptables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) or a similar utility to perform NAT for these hosts over to your main network.

Comment: Are you sure it will work with HTTPS? You will need to spoof the certificates somehow in order for the browser to accept the redirection response (or any kind of response).